# Reset map in Garry's mod without leaving?

Tags: garrys-mod

I saw in a video someone typed something into the console which put the map back in its original state but it happened without them having to restart the map/the game. So they stayed in the game and everything reseted around them. Is this possible? Is it an add on or an in-built console command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type gmod_admin_cleanup in the console

Comment: Will try when I get home. I will just assume it's correct for now. If anyone knows it's not please say